What is this fabric on the inside of my sweater, and what should I do with it?
I have gotten a custom made sweater with an embroidered design. On the backside I found this (see picture below).
I want to know what it is and what to do with it. It feels like fleece and has two layers.
Online I read about embroidery fleece, but I don't know if I should remove it and how. I don't want to damage the sweater.

(click image for larger version)

It is backing for the embroidery, also known as a stabilizer. It has two major functions:

First, the right embroidery backing serves as the stabilizing substrate behind the embroidered design. When you strike the correct combination of backing and material, you’ll prevent the design from warping, rolling and puckering. You’ll also ensure the embroidered design keeps its shape through innumerable wash-and-wear cycles over the life of the garment.
Second, the stabilizer creates a smooth and level barrier between the machine and any seams, textured fabric or other parts of the item being stitched, preventing needle deflection or design registration problems.
source

You can just leave it in/on your sweater (it's not supposed to be removed - removing it without it changing the appearance of the embroidery will be very difficult, if not impossible).
The type of backing depends on the fabric used. There are three major types: water-soluble, tear-away, and cut-away. Based on its thickness, and the fact it has a large margin around the embroidery, the backing of your sweater seems to be of the cut-away kind. Its two layers will simply stabilize the embellishment and improve its durability even more (but we have users here who are much more well-versed in these matters who might correct me on this).

I would add a note that "cut-away" is actually meant to stay in place (one of the lighter-weight varieties is actually called "soft and stay"), not be cut out entirely. Even after construction, leave-in/cut-away stabilizers continue to offer some structure to the embroidery area

Joachim's answer is spot-on and describes the reason why this fabric is there. If it bothers you (I know people who cannot stand the texture or added thickness), you can cut away the backing. Leave at least 1 - 2 cm of the backing around all embroidered parts. I advice against cutting the backing from inside the ring of the chemical element, though. If the fabric stretches in that area, it'll bulge out like a salad bowl.
BTW very nice design ;)

Wouldn't cutting down the margins only increase the abrasion? I suppose there will be more corners and irregularities.

@Joachim I have a light synthetic T shirt with it. The irritation in that case isn't the edges but the overall stiffness. Mine is lines of text and I keep meaning to slit the backing between the lines and maybe between the words (letters are too close together. The edges can't really be felt, at least on the back, and that's against bare skin

Thank you all!!
